# How to shorten long repeating path's and combine statements

Tags: javascript, css

for a website I use tabs with 9 different looks, these are used in different situations. It all works fine but I use a lot of functions with path's and statements that could be a lot shorter I think. An example:

```
function tabAon() {
    tabAvoor=tabAvoor+1;
    tabDrawer=tabDrawer+1;
    tabBvoor=0;
    tabCvoor=0;
    window.document.getElementById("tabA").style.textDecoration="none"; 
    window.document.getElementById("tabB").style.backgroundPosition="-87px -228px";
    window.document.getElementById("tabB").style.color="#898f92";
    window.document.getElementById("tabC").style.backgroundPosition="-190px -228px";
    window.document.getElementById("tabC").style.color="#898f92";
    window.document.getElementById("tabA").style.cursor="pointer";
    if (tabDrawer==0) {
        window.document.getElementById("header").MozTransform="translateY(0px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").msTransform="translateY(0px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").OTransform="translateY(0px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").WebkitTransform="translateY(0px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").transform="translateY(0px)";
        window.document.getElementById("tabA").style.color="#898f92";
        window.document.getElementById("tabA").style.backgroundPosition="0px 0px";
    }
    if (tabDrawer==1) {
        window.document.getElementById("header").style.MozTransform="translateY(36px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").style.msTransform="translateY(36px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").style.OTransform="translateY(36px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").style.WebkitTransform="translateY(36px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").style.transform="translateY(36px)";
        window.document.getElementById("tabAout").style.visibility="visible";
        window.document.getElementById("tabBout").style.visibility="hidden";
        window.document.getElementById("tabCout").style.visibility="hidden";
        window.document.getElementById("tabA").style.color="#000000";
        window.document.getElementById("tabA").style.backgroundPosition="0px -114px";
    }
    if (tabAvoor==2) tabAvoor=1;
    if (tabDrawer==2 && tabBvoor==0 && tabCvoor==0) tabDrawer=0;
    if (tabDrawer==2 && tabBvoor==1 || tabCvoor==1) tabDrawer=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten your code a little by defining a variable for your different IDs:

```
var tabA = window.document.getElementById("tabA");
// window.document.getElementById("tabA").style.textDecoration="none";
tabA.style.textDecoration="none";
```

Comment: Also put the css translate for the #header into a class and add/remove that instead of setting each vendor prefix separately

Comment: Thanks, this is something I earlier tried and even copied again from your code, strangely I can't get it to work, although it sounds logical...

Answer (score 1):

What about using a JS framework? E.g: **[`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/)**

Example:

```
 $('#tabBout').show();
```

Instead of window.document.getElementById("tabAout").style.visibility="visible";

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you should try using some version of jQuery's super cool "$()" function in order to shorten all those "window.document.getElementById" , ie.:

```
function $(id)
{
   return window.document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
$("header").style.MozTransform="translateY(36px)";
```

(btw: there are many other nice things you can do with $(), ie. return entire arrays of objects... the version I've wrote here is just an example)

And you can reduce your code a lot by using some functions, ie.:

```
function set_transforms(id,pos)
{
   $(id).MozTransform="translateY("+pos+"px)";
   $(id).msTransform="translateY("+pos+"px)";
   $(id).OTransform="translateY("+pos+"px)";
   $(id).WebkitTransform="translateY("+pos+"px)";
   $(id).transform="translateY("+pos+"px)";
}
```

So you can replace all this:

```
window.document.getElementById("header").style.MozTransform="translateY(36px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").style.msTransform="translateY(36px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").style.OTransform="translateY(36px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").style.WebkitTransform="translateY(36px)";
        window.document.getElementById("header").style.transform="translateY(36px)";
```

with just this:

```
set_transforms("header",36);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks guys, I gonna try. I guess this is what I needed!